# Render Component By Clicking Text Passed as Props

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to render a component when a user clicks on some text. The text is a state that's updated in a parent component using a form input and the useState React hook. I can find articles on rendering 'onClick' events, but this isn's a form with type submit or a button, it's just text that's passed down to it as a prop from a state higher up. Also a lot of tutorials seem to be outdated. What I would like to do is be able to click on the text and have it render a new component, with the effect of taking the user to a new 'page' in the browser. The rendered text I want to be able to click on is {user.contacts.username} in the code below. Any help much appreciated as I'm not sure which direction to go in.

```
import './Contacts.css';
import CreateTimer from './CreateTimer';


function Contacts(user) {
  return (
    <div className="Contacts">
      {user.contacts.username}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contacts;
```

Comment: You should look at `react-router`: [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried installing `react-router`, but no matter what I do it will not show up in my node modules. There is also no documentation on it in the official react docs. Can you point me to a place that describes how to use it?

Comment: This is the `react-router` I have been trying to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router. But it says "If you are writing an application that will run in the browser, you should instead install react-router-dom". I though this would be simple - in HTML you could use `<a href>`.

Comment: The link I've provided has details on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @MaazSyedAdeeb, got it to work :)